# AIR app in iOS not handling cookies

Tags: ios, air

I have an app which I'm developing in AIR for iOS which interacts with http web services. The web service is setting a cookie in response to requests from the app. In my IDE (PowerFlasher), the cookies are being set, however when the app is running in iOS (6.x and 7.x) the cookie is not being included in the http request.
AIR SDK version is 13.
Is this "normal" behaviour for AIR running in iOS?

Comment: same problem for Android version

Comment: Just thinking aloud here, but could it be a cross-domain security issue? Only thing I can think of.